# Giving inputs to error checking module from PRBS generator in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I have written codes for pattern generator module and error checker module in verilog.
Pattern generator module generates PRBS-7.
The error checker module takes sequences of two 8 bit sequences and tells me the BER( I have verified that through testbench). 
But i am facing trouble in giving inputs to error checker module from pattern generator module. How to do that ?

[PRBS Generator](https://github.com/akhil-123/Integrated-Bit-Error-Ratio-Tester/blob/master/PRBS-7/LFSR.v)
[Error checking Module](https://github.com/akhil-123/Integrated-Bit-Error-Ratio-Tester/blob/master/error-checker/comp.v)

Comment: Please add code to you question. What does the PRBS generator look like, especially the module ports. What does the checker use as input/output signals etc, Also do you need to simulate errors.

Comment: Yes i need to simulate the errors by adding  some error on my own to PRBS and then give input to error checking module. I have edited the question. You can see the links of codes there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a test-bench that contains both modules and connect them up.

To generate artificial errors you have to change one or more bits in the connection between the generator and the checker:

```
wire [7:0] prbs_out,checker_in;
reg  [7:0] make_error;
assign checker_in = prbs_out ^ make_error;
```

As long as `make_error` is all zeros the bits pass unchanged. If you have a test loop you can occasionally make an error using the $random function:

```
   ... // Your major test loop
// 1 in 16 times there is an error
if (($random & 32'h0F)==0)
   make_error = 8'h01;
else
   make_error = 8'h00;
```

Once that is working you then can start playing with the error vector:

```
   // On average 1 in 16 times there is an error
   if (($random & 32'h0F)==0)
      make_error = $random & 32'h00FF; 
   else
      make_error = 8'h00;
```

Note that the above introduces more then one error bit which may pass undetected in some cases.

Comment: How to make test-bench to connect them up and also what is that major test loop for and why 32'h0F ?

Comment: 32'h0F is just an arbitrary number I made up to get 1/16 errors. Your testbench you have to write yourself. You wrote "I have verified that through testbench" so I assume you know how to write a test-bench. In a test-bench there is often a loop to wait a number of clock cycles for all test to finish. That is what I call the major test loop.

Comment: How will it give error only once out of 16 times  - "32'h0F is just an arbitrary number I made up to get 1/16 errors"

Comment: Comment says " On **average** 1 in 16 times". From the 32-bit random number only the bottom 4 bits are left giving a random number in the range 0..15. .  Math says the chance that it is 0 is 1/16.